# Multi-line commands are messed up in my PS1

Tags: bash, prompt, bashrc

```
declare __host='\[\e[30;102m\] \h \[\e[0m\]';
declare __dir='\[\e[1;97;44m\] \w \[\e[22m\]';
declare __arrow='\[\e[1m\]▸ \[\e[0m\]';

function __git_status() {
  local info;
  info=$(__git_info) && printf '\e[30;43m%s' "$info";
}

PS1="$__host$__dir"'$(__git_status)'"$__arrow ";
```

When I go to perform multi-line commands, they wrap back to the starting line. I'm certain it has something to do with escapes in my PS1. I've tried nearly everything I can think of and ended up no where. I'd appreciate any and all help.

The goal is to have the arrow's background color take the color from the previous section. If I'm in a git repo, it should be yellow. If I'm not, it should be blue.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change:

`info=$(__git_info) && printf '\e[30;43m%s' "$info"`

to

`info=$(__git_info) && printf '\1\e[30;43m\2%s' "$info"`

This is because bash internally replaces the prompting special characters [ and ] with ASCII 1 and 2 before my __git_status function is executed.